# Convert data frame with product labels to time series for forecasting in R

Tags: r, date, time-series, forecasting

I am working on a project regarding demand forecasting for pharmaceuticals.

So first of all:

The raw import data which used includes information of; import dates, labels of active pharmaceutical ingredient (Product Code), and quantities in an excel table. For example:

| Import Date | Product Code | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 14/09/2018 | 1 | 300 |
| 18/06/2019 | 1 | 9400 |
| 18/06/2019 | 1 | 5430 |
| 05/06/2019 | 2 | 7000 |
| 17/09/2018 | 3 | 2300 |

First of all i need to merge the same dated and same labelled entries, for example, there is only one importation on 18/06/2019 for product labelled as "1". Also i need to convert the data frame to time series, sorted by dates and with 'Product Code' as a character and 'Quantity' as numeric. When i try with the following code, the result is the following:

```
# Pacman, version 0.4.1 is used to organize the packages used in R.

library(pacman)

p_load(readxl, readr, ggplot2, forecast, fpp2, tidyverse, TTR, dplyr, zoo, xts)

dat <- read_xlsx("C://Users/oozgen/Desktop/Albania Statistical Analysis/labelleddata.xlsx", col_names=T)

# We need to format the 'Import Date' column as Date format (Year/Month), and sort by Date

orderdates <- as.Date(dat$`Import Date`)

# Since labeling is done numerically, we need to convert the 'Product Code' column from numeric format to character format in R.

dat <- transform(dat, 'Product Code' = as.character(dat$`Product Code`), 'Import Date' = orderdates)

dat_ts <- as.xts(x = dat[, -1], order.by = dat$Import.Date)

head(dat_ts)
```

|  | Product.Code | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-01-04 | "784" | " 29976" |
| 2018-01-04 | "1149" | " 200" |
| 2018-01-05 | "306" | " 1000" |
| 2018-01-05 | "713" | " 50" |
| 2018-01-05 | "744" | " 5040" |
| 2018-01-05 | "744" | " 5040" |

Both 'Product Code' and 'Quantity' are in character format. Also you might have noticed, it will be difficult to forecast for separate products on a single table. Do i have to separate all products to different tables and forecast them separately?

You can access to a sample data set from this link*.

- https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1R2Wt5Mr2ISKK56X7RZV8lPjHLpeMPe1L/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=107030456235197826940&rtpof=true&sd=true

First Edit, i have worked on the solution which @g-grothendieck shared:

```
# Pacman, version 0.4.1 is used to organize the packages used in R.

library(pacman)

p_load(readxl, readr, ggplot2, forecast, fpp3, tidyverse, TTR, dplyr, zoo, xts)

dat <- read_xlsx("C://Users/oozgen/Desktop/Albania Statistical Analysis/labelleddata.xlsx", col_names=T)

# We need to format the 'Import Date' column as Date format (Year/Month), and sort by Date. And also since labeling is done numerically, we need to convert the 'Product Code' column from numeric format to character format in R.

dat <- transform(dat, 'Product Code' = as.character(dat$`Product Code`), 'Import Date' = as.yearmon(dat$`Import Date`, "%Y/%m"))

class(dat)

[1] "data.frame"
```

My data is tidied up as this, as data.frame:

|  | Import.Date | Product.Code | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sep 2018 | 1 | 3000 |
| 2 | Mar 2019 | 1 | 600 |
| 3 | Mar 2019 | 1 | 930 |
| 4 | Jun 2019 | 1 | 2202 |
| 5 | Jun 2019 | 1 | 5900 |
| 6 | Jun 2019 | 1 | 5630 |

and then i continue but get this error:

```
> x <- dat |>
+   type.convert(as.is = TRUE) |>
+   read.zoo(format = "%Y/%m", split = "Product Code", aggregate = sum) |>
+   as.xts()
Error in `[.data.frame`(rval, , split) : undefined columns selected
```

An addition to my First Edit (edit v1.1.); @g-grothendieck showed, i've made a mistake with a column name, and corrected it. And the code follows as this:

```
x <- dat |>
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE) |>
  read.zoo(format = "%Y/%m", split = "Product.Code", aggregate = sum) |>
  as.xts()
```

and i received the following error:

```
...
+   as.xts()
Error in read.zoo(type.convert(dat, as.is = TRUE), format = "%Y/%m", split = "Product.Code",  : 
  index has 33038 bad entries at data rows: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100 ...
```

An addition to my First Edit's Edit (edit v1.2.); with the help of @g-grothendieck, the code has finally compiled with 'Product Code's separately, using the zoo package and the `as.yearmon` command:

```
x <- dat |>
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE) |>
  read.zoo(format = "%b %Y", FUN = as.yearmon,  split = "Product.Code", aggregate = sum) |>
  as.xts()

x[is.na(x)] <- 0

tt <- merge(x, zoo(, seq(start(x), end(x), 1/12))) |>
  na.spline() |>
  as.ts()
```

and the output data is time series, with a tidier fashion. Also i can manipulate different product group with different frequencies using `as.yearqtr` (also addition from @g-grothendieck)

For the 2nd Edit, i have converted date to month/year and followed the codes which @rob-hyndman presented:

```
# Pacman, version 0.4.1 is used to organize the packages used in R.

library(pacman)

p_load(readxl, readr, ggplot2, forecast, fpp3, tidyverse, TTR, dplyr, zoo, janitor, xts)

dat <- read_xlsx("C://Users/oozgen/Desktop/Albania Statistical Analysis/labelleddata.xlsx", col_names=T)

# We need to format the 'Import Date' column as Date format (Year/Month), and sort by Date. And also since labeling is done numerically, we need to convert the 'Product Code' column from numeric format to character format in R.

dat <- transform(dat, 'Product Code' = as.character(dat$`Product Code`), 'Import Date' = as.yearmon(dat$`Import Date`, "%Y/%m"))

class(dat)

dat[is.na(dat)]=0

write.csv(dat,"C:/Users/oozgen/Downloads/data2.csv", row.names = FALSE)

x <- readr::read_csv(
  "C:/Users/oozgen/Downloads/data2.csv",
  name_repair = janitor::make_clean_names
) %>%
  mutate(
    # Interpret dates
    import_date = dmy(import_date),
    # Format product codes as character strings with leading zeros
    product_code = sprintf("%03d",product_code)
  ) %>%
  # Make date/code combinations unique
  group_by(import_date, product_code) %>%
  summarise(quantity = sum(quantity), .groups="drop") %>%
  # Create tsibble
  as_tsibble(index=import_date, key=product_code) %>%
  # Fill missing dates with zeros
  fill_gaps(quantity = 0)
```

and i received this error:

```
...
+   fill_gaps(quantity = 0)
Rows: 33038 Columns: 3                                                                                                                  
-- Column specification -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Delimiter: ","
chr (1): import_date
dbl (2): product_code, quantity

i Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.
i Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.
Error: Column `import_date` (index) must not contain `NA`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
In addition: Warning message:
Problem with `mutate()` column `import_date`.
i `import_date = dmy(import_date)`.
i All formats failed to parse. No formats found.
```

that i can't continue on forecasting...

For my 2nd Edit's Edit (edit v2.1.); @rob-hyndman explained that the error happens because i've edited the date before using the code, so the function will no longer be able to interpret the dates. I've fixed it my code as following:

```
dat <- readr::read_csv(
  "C://Users/oozgen/Desktop/Albania Statistical Analysis/labelleddata.csv",
  name_repair = janitor::make_clean_names
) %>%
  mutate(
    # Interpret dates
    import_date = quarter(dmy(import_date), with_year = T),
    # Format product codes as character strings with leading zeros
    product_code = sprintf("%03d", product_code)
  ) %>%
  # Make date/code combinations unique
  group_by(import_date, product_code) %>%
  summarise(quantity = sum(quantity), .groups="drop") %>%
  # Create tsibble
  as_tsibble(index=import_date, key=product_code) %>%
  # Fill missing dates with zeros
  fill_gaps(quantity = 0)
```

It has compiled without errors, you might have noticed. I've re-edited this line; `import_date = quarter(dmy(import_date), with_year = T),` because import aren't frequent, most of the pharmaceuticals imported three or four times in year, so i've changed the dates to/as quarterly. and then i proceed to forecast as @rob-hyndman suggested:

```
fc <- dat %>%
  model(croston = CROSTON(quantity)) %>%
  forecast(h = "12 quarters")
Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `croston`.
i `croston = (function (object, ...) ...`.
x invalid class “Period” object: periods must have integer values
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
In addition: Warning message:
195 errors (1 unique) encountered for croston
[195] At least two non-zero values are required to use Croston's method.
```

And i've received that error... Any methods that i can forecast with quarterly data.

3rd and the FINAL EDIT:

With the help of brute force, i've successfully forecasted all of the data at once:

```
# Pacman, version 0.4.1 is used to organize the packages used in R.

library(pacman)

p_load(readxl, readr, ggplot2, forecast, fpp3, tidyverse, TTR, tibble, tsibble, tsibbledata, feasts, fable, dplyr, zoo, lubridate, janitor, xts)

dat <- read_xlsx("C://Users/oozgen/Desktop/Albania Statistical Analysis/dat.xlsx", col_names=T)

# We need to format the 'Import Date' column as Date format (Year/Month), and sort by Date. And also since labeling is done numerically, we need to convert the 'Product Code' column from numeric format to character format in R.

dat <- transform(dat, 'Product Code' = as.character(dat$`Product Code`))

class(dat)

z <- dat %>%
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>%
  read.zoo(format = "%Y-%m-%d", FUN = as.yearqtr, index.column = 1,
           split = "Product.Code", aggregate = sum)

tt <- merge(z, zoo(, seq(start(z), end(z), 1/4))) |>
  as.ts()

tt[is.na(tt)]=0

result_matrix <- matrix(, nrow = 20, ncol = 1149)

for(i in 1:1149){
  
  res_i <- croston(tt[, i], h=8)
    res_i <- append(res_i$x, res_i$mean)
      result_matrix[, i] <- res_i
  
  }

write.table(result_matrix, "resultmatrix.csv", sep = ";")
```

Since croston method for forecasting is valid for intermittent demand. I've to organize the data according to infrequently imported pharmaceuticals and frequently imported pharmaceuticals. And for the frequent ones, i should find a suitable method for forecasting.

This will be the last entry for this post. I'll probably post the data set and the related codes and algorithm in github. Many thanks to @sevgib, @g-grothendieck and @rob-hyndman for their help.

P.S. It would be great if there could be a way to use deep learning algorithms for demand forecasting of pharmaceutical products. There was a study which included Facebook AI packages for pandemic forecasting, i think this one*

- https://ai.facebook.com/blog/using-ai-to-help-health-experts-address-the-covid-19-pandemic/

Answer (score 1):

Using DF shown in the Note at the end, convert the columns that should be numeric to numeric, use `read.zoo` using yearmon class for the index, splitting on Product Code (check that the format and column name are specified exactly for your data if different from that assumed in the Note at the end) and aggregating using sum and convert to zoo.  At the end interpolate by merging z with a zero width series having every month and then filling in the missing values using `na.spline` (or `na.approx` or `na.locf`) and then convert to ts class since a regularly spaced `ts` series is needed by many forecasting routines.  If you do want an xts series then use as.xts(z) or replace the `as.ts()` with `as.xts()` if  you still want the interpolation.  Read `?strptime` for the percent codes, `?read.zoo` and `vignette("zoo-read")` for `read.zoo`, `?yearmon` for info on that class and `?type.convert` for that function.

```
library(xts) # also pulls in zoo

z <- DF |>
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE) |>
  read.zoo(format = "%d/%m/%Y", FUN = as.yearmon, 
    split = "Product Code", aggregate = sum) 

tt <- merge(z, zoo(, seq(start(z), end(z), 1/12))) |>
  na.spline() |>
  as.ts()
```

giving:

```
> tt
                 1    2    3
Sep 2018   300.000 7000 2300
Oct 2018  1914.444 7000 2300
Nov 2018  3528.889 7000 2300
Dec 2018  5143.333 7000 2300
Jan 2019  6757.778 7000 2300
Feb 2019  8372.222 7000 2300
Mar 2019  9986.667 7000 2300
Apr 2019 11601.111 7000 2300
May 2019 13215.556 7000 2300
Jun 2019 14830.000 7000 2300
```

### Note

```
DF <- structure(list(`Import Date` = c("14/09/2018", "18/06/2019", 
"18/06/2019", "05/06/2019", "17/09/2018"), `Product Code` = c("1", 
"1", "1", "2", "3"), Quantity = c("300", "9400", "5430", "7000", 
"2300")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Also a small addition as na.spline() smooths the noise very well (the data won't go super saiyan now :) ). I will start to work on various labels, and try to find correlation between competitor drugs at first. Many thanks to you and this community.

Comment: If  you have a lot of missing months you might want to use as.yearqtr instead of as.yearmon and do quarterly forecasting instead.  In that case replace 1/12 later in the code with 1/4.

Comment: Works like a charm :) For instance, Biologic Products have expensive storage and transportation requirements so distributors buy less frequently but with higher volume. And there are generic products which used for common cold, bought once or twice a year. I think i need to manipulate the data and group them, and forecast each group with different frequencies.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this would be with the fable package, which is designed to handle multiple time series at once, and integrates with the tidyverse collection of packages. Here is an example using your sample data.

```r
library(fpp3)
#> ── Attaching packages ─────────────────────────────────────── fpp3 0.4.0.9000 ──
#> ✓ tibble      3.1.4          ✓ tsibble     1.0.1     
#> ✓ dplyr       1.0.7          ✓ tsibbledata 0.3.0.9000
#> ✓ tidyr       1.1.3          ✓ feasts      0.2.2.9000
#> ✓ lubridate   1.7.10         ✓ fable       0.3.1.9000
#> ✓ ggplot2     3.3.5
#> ── Conflicts ───────────────────────────────────────────────── fpp3_conflicts ──
#> x lubridate::date()    masks base::date()
#> x dplyr::filter()      masks stats::filter()
#> x tsibble::intersect() masks base::intersect()
#> x tsibble::interval()  masks lubridate::interval()
#> x dplyr::lag()         masks stats::lag()
#> x tsibble::setdiff()   masks base::setdiff()
#> x tsibble::union()     masks base::union()
# Read data and clean up
dat <- readr::read_csv(
    "~/Downloads/albaniaingredient_result.xlsx - Sheet1.csv",
    name_repair = janitor::make_clean_names
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    # Interpret dates
    import_date = dmy(import_date),
    # Format product codes as character strings with leading zeros
    product_code = sprintf("%03d",product_code)
  ) %>%
  # Make date/code combinations unique
  group_by(import_date, product_code) %>%
  summarise(quantity = sum(quantity), .groups="drop") %>%
  # Create tsibble
  as_tsibble(index=import_date, key=product_code) %>%
  # Fill missing dates with zeros
  fill_gaps(quantity = 0)
#> Rows: 3086 Columns: 3
#> ── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> Delimiter: ","
#> chr (1): import_date
#> dbl (2): product_code, quantity
#> 
#> ℹ Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.
#> ℹ Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.
# Produce daily forecasts
fc <- dat %>%
  model(croston = CROSTON(quantity)) %>%
  forecast(h = "14 days")
#> Warning: 16 errors (1 unique) encountered for croston
#> [16] At least two non-zero values are required to use Croston's method.
# forecasts for product 014
fc %>%
  filter(product_code == "014")
#> # A fable: 14 x 5 [1D]
#> # Key:     product_code, .model [1]
#>    product_code .model  import_date quantity .mean
#>    <chr>        <chr>   <date>        <dist> <dbl>
#>  1 014          croston 2020-12-04  4773.584 4774.
#>  2 014          croston 2020-12-05  4773.584 4774.
#>  3 014          croston 2020-12-06  4773.584 4774.
#>  4 014          croston 2020-12-07  4773.584 4774.
#>  5 014          croston 2020-12-08  4773.584 4774.
#>  6 014          croston 2020-12-09  4773.584 4774.
#>  7 014          croston 2020-12-10  4773.584 4774.
#>  8 014          croston 2020-12-11  4773.584 4774.
#>  9 014          croston 2020-12-12  4773.584 4774.
#> 10 014          croston 2020-12-13  4773.584 4774.
#> 11 014          croston 2020-12-14  4773.584 4774.
#> 12 014          croston 2020-12-15  4773.584 4774.
#> 13 014          croston 2020-12-16  4773.584 4774.
#> 14 014          croston 2020-12-17  4773.584 4774.
fc %>%
  filter(product_code == "014") %>%
  autoplot(filter(dat, year(import_date) >= 2020))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

I've used Croston's method because your data has far too many zeros for most methods. If you aggregated the data to weekly or monthly, you would then be able to use more reliable methods.

A textbook discussing the fable package is freely available online at [OTexts.com/fpp3](https://OTexts.com/fpp3)

Comment: Thank you, i've tried and shared the error under "For the 2nd Edit" paragraph. Can you kindly examine it?

Comment: If you've converted the data to month-year, then the `dmy()` function will no longer be able to interpret the dates.

Comment: Thank you, i've fixed it. And then i try to change my date format to quarterly with lubridate's "quarter" command, but the forecast method doesn't work.

Comment: I've shared the error and the code used under "edit v2.1.", can you kindly check it? @rob-hyndman